# How to convert a GeoSeries of points to a list of tuples (lat, lon) using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a GeoPandas dataframe named `barrios` and I use `barrios.geometry.centroid` and assign it to `center`.

So `center` is `geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries`  with an index and values - `POINT (-58.42266 -34.57393)`

**I need to get these coordinates and save them as a list**:

```
[(point_1_lat, point_1_lon), (point_2_lat, point_2_lon), ...]
```

I tried:

```
[center.values.y , center.values.x]
```

But it returns a list of 2 arrays - `[array(lat), array(lng)]`.

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the `zip` to loop through multiple variables. This should extract the coordinates to a list.

```
coord_list = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(gdf['geometry'].x , gdf['geometry'].y)]
```

alternatively, you can create a `GeoDataFrame` with the x and y coordinates.
first, extract the x and y coordinates and put them in new columns.

```
import geopandas as gpd
url = r"link\to\file"
gdf = gpd.read_file(url)

gdf['x'] = None
gdf['y'] = None

gdf['x'] = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.x)
gdf['y'] = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.y)
```

this returns a `GeoDataFrame` with x and y coordinate columns. Now extracting the coordinates into the list.

```
coordinate_list = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(gdf.x , gdf.y)]
```

this return the list of coordinate tuples

```
[(105.27, -5.391),
 (107.615, -6.945264),
 (107.629, -6.941126700000001),
 (107.391, -6.9168726),
 (107.6569, -6.9087003),
 (107.638, -6.9999),
 (107.67, -6.553),
 (107.656, -6.8),
 ...
```

you'll have a list, and a GeoDataFrame with x and y columns.

Comment: vector.geometry.apply(lambda x: (x.x, x.y)) do the job in one step