# Convert GeoSeries to list of tuples

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a GeoSeries as below.

```
u           v           key
5863596387  5863593976  0      POINT (585155.331 4507719.832)
7480515814  7787627737  0      POINT (585156.356 4507160.458)
8309479770  8309479778  0      POINT (585008.639 4509646.314)
1205714997  1764647101  0      POINT (590176.344 4524086.390)
7604384203  7604384200  0      POINT (589636.237 4522156.767)
7924346623  7924346668  0      POINT (589841.836 4516372.368)
1774037211  1792517013  0      POINT (587815.517 4517574.111)
8279851489  8279851474  0      POINT (583614.400 4507554.406)
7580661034  4024142484  0      POINT (583284.669 4506201.572)
3900961247  3900964258  0      POINT (589095.692 4515465.756)
7924099735  7924099740  0      POINT (588136.098 4514814.989)
60918736    60925795    0      POINT (589377.465 4522528.968)
42445215    3858909357  0      POINT (588907.958 4517605.588)
61271527    61272997    0      POINT (585439.051 4514947.585)
5815643321  5813259923  0      POINT (583241.942 4507490.863)
42456831    371337197   0      POINT (589885.624 4518773.023)
8309479036  8309479035  0      POINT (584918.567 4509003.683)
7925258675  7926756848  0      POINT (590145.751 4517162.307)
```

I would like to convert this into list of points, for example:

```
[(585155.331, 4507719.832), (585156.356, 4507160.458), ...]
```

How can I accomplish this in python? I am not sure how to get the POINT column because unlike the u,v, key columns, they are not indexed.

I have seen [How to convert a GeoSeries of points to a list of tuples (lat, lon) using GeoPandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625931/how-to-convert-a-geoseries-of-points-to-a-list-of-tuples-lat-lon-using-geopan) this answer, but I get an error in their solution (KeyError: 'geometry') and am not sure what "geometry" refers to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use accessors `x` and `y`:

```
# Ensure you have a GeoDataFrame
>>> type(gdf)
geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame

>>> list(zip(gdf.x.astype(float), plugs.y.astype(float)))
[(837345.1, 6502334.7),
 (837344.9, 6502334.8),
 (837262.6, 6502120.7),
 (837262.4, 6502120.6),
 (837331.0, 6501996.9),
 (837331.2, 6501996.7)]
```